# Tensorflow retrain neural network with different data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a list of `inputs` to the neural network for example

```
list_of_inputs = [inputs1, inputs2, inputs3, ... ,inputsN]
```

*and also a corresponding list of labels *

```
list_of_labels = [label1, label2, label3, ..., labelN]
```

I want to feed/train each pair of `input,label` into the neural network, record the loss and then train the next pair of `input,label` on the same network and record the loss, etc. for all the  `input,label` pairs.

Note: I don't want to reinitialize the weights every time a new `input,label` is added, I want to use the trained weights from the previous pair. The network is shown below ( where you can see I am also printing the loss). How would I go about this?

```
with tf.name_scope("nn"):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(64, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
        tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(np.squeeze(labels).shape[0])
    ])

logits = model(inputs)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(labels - logits))
train_op_bnn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)


init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(100):   
        sess.run(train_op_bnn)
        print(sess.run(loss))
```

EDIT:

The issue is that when I try to format the network in a function as below:

```
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    inputs,labels = MEMORY[0]

    logits, model_losses = build_graph(inputs)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(labels - logits))
    train_op_bnn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

    sess.run(train_op_bnn)
    print(sess.run(loss))
```

I get an error:

```
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-5ca77fa0606a> in <module>()
     36     train_op_bnn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
     37 
---> 38     sess.run(train_op_bnn)
     39     print(sess.run(loss))
     40
```

Comment: Wait so what's wrong with the code above and why doesn't it suit your needs? I'm confused

Comment: A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031324/how-to-implement-multivariate-linear-stochastic-gradient-descent-algorithm-in-te) to your question. Basically you're asking for an implementation of stochastic gradient descent in tf.

Comment: Hi @IanQuah I have edited the question to explain the problem in a bit more detail

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  I have edited the question to explain the problem in a bit more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logits, model_losses = build_graph(inputs)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(labels - logits))
train_op_bnn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

should be above

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

and above your `init_op` definition

Comment: This worked out! Can you briefly explain how you realized this?

Comment: `FailedPreconditionError`, which I googled and then realized that you defined your losses and train op within the session

Comment: Ah okay. So the key thing to take out of this is that you can't define losses and trainop within a session. Thanks!